# How to use form validation on ion-select in Ionic 3

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic3

I am new to Ionic 3. I am not able to use form validation on ion-select in ionic 3.

**html**

```
   <ion-item class="side-heading-background delivery-date-header" no-lines>
        <ion-label color="side-heading-color">{{"Select Delivery Date and Time" | translate}} </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Select a Date</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newDate" interface ="popover">
            <div *ngFor="let newDate of dates">
            <ion-option >{{newDate}}</ion-option>
            </div>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Select Time</ion-label>
          <ion-select  [(ngModel)] ="item" interface ="popover">
            <div *ngFor="let item of items">
               <ion-option > {{item}}</ion-option>
            </div>
          </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

I want user can not place an order until the user does not select a delivery date and delivery time. If he placed an order without selecting date and time it will show an error pop of *"Please Select delivery and time"*. How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **ngIf** directive for ion-label element. 
I've added it to your code: ***ngIf="hasError"**.

**html**

```
<ion-item class="side-heading-background delivery-date-header" no-lines>
    <ion-label *ngIf="hasError" color="side-heading-color">{{"Select Delivery Date and Time" | translate}} </ion-label>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select a Date</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newDate" interface ="popover">
        <div *ngFor="let newDate of dates">
            <ion-option >{{newDate}}</ion-option>
        </div>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select Time</ion-label>
    <ion-select  [(ngModel)] ="item" interface ="popover">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
            <ion-option > {{item}}</ion-option>
        </div>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

And handler for your button:

```
<button ion-button (tap)="tapPlaceOrder()">Place order</button>
```

And define your **handler** and **hasError**

**TS**

```
  item: any;
  newDate: any;
  hasError: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  tapPlaceOrder() {

    if (!this.item || !this.newDate) {
       this.hasError = true;
       return;
    }

    this.hasError = false;

    /* place order */

  }
```

Comment: i hope it help you

Comment: its not working.This disable the whole div.Now delivery date and time option is not visible.